# Position of 'such' as a determiner, before a noun

Tags: difference, legalese

> [[Source:]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garcetti_v._Ceballos) Additionally, Breyer wrote that the Constitution itself imposed speech obligations on professional employees. For example, a prosecutor has a constitutional obligation to preserve, and to communicate with the defense about exculpatory evidence in the possession of the government.<sup>[[10]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garcetti_v._Ceballos#cite_note-10)</sup> Therefore, where there are both ♦ professional and constitutional **such** obligations, "the need to protect the employee’s speech is augmented, the need for broad government authority is likely diminished, and administrable standards are quite likely available." ...

1. What are the similarities and differences between placing **such**: at the lozenge (♦) vs its present location? The present sounds strange and wrong to me, but is it?

2. Am I right that in either of the 2 positions, **such** functions as a determiner here?

Comment: This is not grammatical. Either: *Therefore, where such obligations are both professional and constitional, 'the need to protect....* or *Therefore, where there are both professional and constitutional obligations, 'the need to protect...'*

Comment: Too late to fix the first typo.

Comment: Or a third (awkward but grammatical) possibility: *Therefore, where there are, both professionally and constitutionally, such obligations, 'the need to protect...'*

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the offered construction is awkward at best and grammatically incorrect at worst. Again, when analytical focus is on the propriety of one word, very often the broader problem is the surrounding sentence, not the word itself. This is an excellent example of precisely that problem.

In this case, the writer is treating the two obligations as mutual and distinct, when a careful reading demonstrates they are a single obligation despite the use of the plural *obligations*. Note the text:

```
 Additionally, Breyer wrote that the Constitution itself imposed
 speech obligations on professional employees.
```

There are not two obligations; there is a single obligation imposed by the Constitution on what is termed 'professional speech.' The single obligation is reinforced by the subsequent example involving a prosecuting attorney's communication of exculpatory evidence to a defendant. In the context of the writing, there is no professional speech obligation outside that defined by the Constitution; therefore, the subsequent differentiation of the obligation into *distinct* entities in the next sentence is, in fact, the error in structure. The word 'such' is merely a symptom of that error.

I would respectfully submit the following reconstruction of the second sentence:

> "Therefore, where there exists a constitutionally mandated obligation
>   for professional speech, "the need to protect the employee’s speech is
>   augmented, the need for broad government authority is likely
>   diminished, and administrable standards are quite likely available."

Answer (score 1):

I think the current phrasing is grammatical, but very lawyerly; I would never expect to see it in ordinary speech or writing. The Wikipedia paragraph is probably too close a paraphrase of a legal source, or else perhaps it was written by someone who is too used to legal writing.

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) considers *such* to be an adjective, and in a sentence like this one it is an internal modifier. However, CGEL does not seem to give any examples where *such* is preceded by ordinary lexical adjectives like *professional* and *constitutional*. (Of course, phrases like "many such obligations" and "one such obligation" and so on are found even outside of lawyerly writing, and CGEL has many examples of these, e.g. on page 1546.)

Its role here is anaphoric; "[…] such obligations" means "[…] speech obligations", in reference to the phrase "speech obligations" two sentences before.

Your proposed phrasing, "both such professional and constitutional obligations", does not work, because the *both* here is correlated with the *and* (cf. "both left and right"); your phrasing would restrict the scope of *such* to *such professional*, which doesn't match the meaning that is being conveyed.

Comment: Well, the wikipedia article is about a Supreme Court decision, so I would expect it to sound lawyerly!  -   The other thing that bothers me about this is "restrict the scope of SUCH to PROFESSIONAL."  Consider this sentence: "She has many important professional and constitutional obligations."  "Important" describes both nouns, not just the first one.

Comment: @aparente001: Re: "Well, the wikipedia article is about a Supreme Court decision, so I would expect it to sound lawyerly!": So would you expect articles about mothers to sound maternal, and articles about pop culture to sound colloquial? Of course not. Wikipedia is an encyclopedia, and it aims for an encyclopedic tone. Since it's collaboratively edited, it sometimes falls short of that aim, but that doesn't mean that it aims to fail.

Comment: @aparente001: Re: "Consider this sentence: 'She has many important professional and constitutional obligations.' 'Important' describes both nouns, not just the first one": You left out the word "both", so it's not a valid comparison. If you correct the analogy to \*"She has both many important professional and constitutional obligations", you'll see that it no longer works, because "important" can no longer have the necessary scope. (Incidentally, "important" modifies only one noun in your example, namely "obligations". "Professional" and "constitutional" are adjectives.)

Comment: I see what you mean now.  -  I wish I knew what we're trying to do here -- rewrite a troublesome sentence in a Wikipedia article?  If so, I'll suggest "there are both professional and constitutional obligations of this type."

Comment: @aparente001: If you're looking to edit the article, I'd suggest just changing "such obligations" to "speech obligations". The previous occurrence is two sentences earlier, so I don't think it will sound awkwardly repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, where there are both such professional and constitutional
>   obligations, etc.

This works fine.  Putting "such" later, after "constitutional," sounds wrong -- but within a legal context, who knows?

It's not a determiner, it's an adjective.  Please see http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such